# Can I use any fuzzy search tricks in CMake find_library?

Tags: cmake

My motivation comes from this:
I want to find a library named libboost_python38.so, if I use find_library command like this, I cannot find the library:

```
find_library(USD_BOOST_PYTHON boost_python HINTS ${USD_LIBRARY_DIRECTORY})
```

Only when I use this command, the library can be found:

```
find_library(USD_BOOST_PYTHON boost_python38 HINTS ${USD_LIBRARY_DIRECTORY})
```

This method will make my cmake file lose some cross platform capabilities, so I hope to search this library by some fuzzy search method. Can I do this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

No particularly, but you can use the `NAMES` parameter, and pass a few candid names that `find_library` should look for, see [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/command/find_library.html). You can also provide a few different `PATH` and `PATH_SUFFIXES` which could help.

If you still need more logic to find your library, then you most likely need to deal with them before your `find_library` call, e.g., conclude the name of your library beforehand, put it in a variable, and pass that as the name of the library to the `find_library`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `find_library` for this purpose. Instead make use of the fact that boost comes with cmake configuration scripts and use [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html).

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python)
target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE Boost::python)
```

This has the added benefit of any dependencies being added to `my_target` automatically alongside the necessary include directories.

If you've installed the package to the default location, no additional info should be required. If you've built boost yourself and installed it to a non-standard location, you may need to provide info about the install location, e.g. by adding the install location to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Note: `find_package` has additional parameters that allow you to restrict the acceptable boost version if desired.